# Pandas: how to select only the duplicate rows that have the same key but different values in a column

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe with columns`['join key', 'code', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D']`.

The `join key` is a long string of characters while `code` can either be equal to 521, 539 or a bunch of others numbers.

There can be rows with the same `join key`.

I want to be able to group by `join key` my records and ONLY have all those duplicate records that appear in my dataframe with the `code` field set to both 521 and 539.

I do NOT want those records that may have the same key and `code=521` but no `code=539`counterpart.

Once I have all the pair of duplicates I want to apply a function, `compute(x)` that will merge the pair into one row made of the `['A', 'B']` columns from the row with `code=521` and the `['C', 'D']` columns from the row with `code=539`.

I can't seem to select to right rows. I keep selecting those rows that are duplicate on `join key` but are all of the same code with not counterpart.

```
import pandas as pd
exp_csv = pd.DataFrame([[3566190983, 521, 1, 2, 3, 4], \
                        [3566190983, 539, 1, 2, 3, 4], \
                        [3509730366, 521, 1, 2, 3, 4], \
                        [3509730366, 521, 1, 2, 3, 4], \
                        [3509730366, 521, 1, 2, 3, 4], \
                        [9809730686, 500, 1, 2, 3, 4]],\
                        columns=['join key', 'code', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])

interim = exp_csv[exp_csv.duplicated(['join key'], keep=False)]
interim = interim.loc[(interim['code'] == 521) | (interim['code'] == 539)]
interim = interim.groupby(by='join key').apply(lambda x: compute(x))
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you need compare `set`s and filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
mask = exp_csv.groupby('join key')['code'].transform(lambda x: set(x) == set([521, 539]))
interim = exp_csv[mask]
print (interim)
     join key  code  A  B  C  D
0  3566190983   521  1  2  3  4
1  3566190983   539  1  2  3  4
```

Comment: Thank you, that does indeed work! But how could I also add up the two rows? Maybe I could groupby again by key and the apply a function on each pair?

Comment: Is there a way to combine two rows in the way I explained in the OP? I would like to have a new row with only columns`['join key', 'code', 'A', 'B']` from one row and only columns `['C', 'D']` from the other row.
I thought about setting some columns to `nan` and then summing the two rows but I can't seem to do it.